# The right side of some pages on my site are cut off

Tags: css

The right side of our pages get cut off.... usually its because if a larger image for a product.

I have the main image for each parent product (larger grey box) marked with `style="max-width:300px;"` but the pages are still getting cut off on smaller screens. The crazy thing is the smaller images for each of the product lines inside the grey box are resizing...

I've had this issue on our site for a while now and I thought I had it fixed but it has popped back and I can't seem to make it stay away.

The issue used to be browser specific - now I'm seeing it on Firefox, Chrome and IE. A customer has also reported it on an Ipad. The page renders fine if the screen is large. It also renders fine on my android tablet and phone.

I'm not certain its due to images but it is my first guess. Page loads fine if images are not there or are smaller.

You can see the problem here
http://theringlord.com/cart/shopdisplayproducts.asp?id=232&cat=Shield+Scale+Kits

It's an open source shopping cart with templates and old code - the code is ASP. Yes I'd love to update and use something more this decade but this is what it is now.

Comment: i couldn't find any min-width causing it but something is keeping your content from getting narrower than 963px or so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the content is in a div with a class of *columns*.

Lines 226 and 52 of layout.css specify the width to be 100% with overflow:hidden.

The content contains tables which cannot be squashed up indefinitely, as the page width decreases, the tables reduce in width to a point where they can't be reduced any further. The minimum width for the table is approximately 1245px. As the browser size decreases beyond this, say to 800px, the 1245px wide table is now wider than the 100% wide div (which is now 800px wide) that contains it. The overflow:hidden then hides that portion of the table which overflows the div.

To fix, either make the content more squashable, or remove / adjust the <strike>rel</strike>css

Comment: Thanks for that. 
What would "make the content more squishable"?
What do you mean by remove/adjust "relcss"?

Comment: I removed the overflow:hidden and it not allows scrolling to the right and you can see the content! 
Great fix for now. Thanks!
Is there a better practice I can implement?

Comment: Sorry, relcss should have said css.As for better practice, the site is choc full of nested tables which is a bit frowned upon; see [link]http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm[/link] for one explanation.

Comment: Restructuring the site to use a tableless structure would allow you to have a page that reflows as the page decreases in size. See [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) for an example.

Comment: Thank you - not sure I can remedy that problem using the current cart software but I will certainly keep it in mind as the site is improved.